# WordPress loop get post not page single

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, templates

I am trying to get latest posts to display through a template page i am building for pages, the loop is not running the latest post only one page

ok, I have a simple loop that gets latest post

**my loop**

```
            <?php
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
            endwhile; endif;
            ?>
```

**and content.php**

```
<div class="blog-post">

    <h2 class="blog-post-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>

    <p class="blog-post-meta">
        <?php the_date(); ?>by <a href="#"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>">
            <?php printf(_nx('One Comment', '%1$s Comments', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'textdomain'), number_format_i18n(get_comments_number())); ?>
        </a>
    </p>

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php   the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

when i run the loop in index.php i get my latest blog post, perfect.

however, i am building a template page, i try and include the loop in this page,  i just get one page (not all posts).

**my template**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            // content bar
            <?php get_template_part('advicecentre_bar', get_post_format()) ?>

            // cmd driven content
            <?php
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                get_template_part('content_page', get_post_format());
            endwhile; endif;
            ?>

            // recent post
            <?php
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
            endwhile; endif;
            ?>


        </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div> <!-- /.row -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using multiple loops on the same page, you must use [`rewind_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts) like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        // content bar
        <?php get_template_part('advicecentre_bar', get_post_format()); ?>

        // cmd driven content
        <?php
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            get_template_part('content_page', get_post_format());
        endwhile; endif;
        ?>

        <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

        // recent post
        <?php
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
        endwhile; endif;
        ?>


    </div> <!-- /.col -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This "resets" the loop to it's original state and allows you to look through the posts again. In your original code you scan through all the posts, and then in your second loop scan through nothing, as you have already scanned through all the posts!

Comment: Hmm interesting, +1 for helping me understand. however, its not fixing my problem. I am still only seeing the page in working on show as the loop output not all recent post

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I have found this solution using a for each rather than the while loop seems to work, but im not sure if its the best way around.

```
             <ul>
                <?php
                $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
                foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
                    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
                }
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
            </ul>
```

UPDATE

```
   <?php
    $args = array('numberposts' => 5);
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    foreach ($recent_posts as $recent) {
        $excerpt = wp_trim_excerpt($recent['post_content']);
        $permalink = get_permalink($recent["ID"]);
        $title = esc_attr($recent["post_title"]);
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail');
        echo '<li><a href="' . $permalink . '" title="Look ' . $title . '" >' . $thumbnail . $title . '</a></li>';
        echo $excerpt;
    }
    ?>
```